# What is FF Info Guarded 4.6.5?

Tags: firefox, malware, firefox-extensions

On a Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS that I administrate from time to time I found the Firefox extension "FF Info Guarded 4.6.5". Firefox version is 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

On about:support is it listed with the id "{0c4df994-4f4a-4646-ae5d-8936be8a4188}". I googled about it, but could not find anything related to it. [Virustotal has 0 detections for it.](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/5214278656b1d46bf4814febbc1de3e62f50523854624dfecf34e3ee6bd3ecdb/detection)

**What does this extension do? Is it malware?**

Comment: Why can’t you just remove it?

Comment: I can. But I want to unterstand if if provided a risk to the user and if I need to clean up or change passwords ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the code inside of the xpi file and found that

- it prevents the user from using "about:addons" (automatically closes the tab)
- makes request to this domains: searchingvnm.com, apiurl.org, infoguardedff.com, spidtest.org, infoguardedext.com. The whois information for this domains are all protected

**Conclusion: It is at least some sort of tracking software or adware.**